# $tr(A)=0$ then exists $P,Q$ such that $A=PQ-QP$ .

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

> Let $\mathbb{F}$ be an arbitrary field and $A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{F})$ such that $$tr(A)=0$$
>   Now show that there exists $P$,$Q$ $\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{F})$ such that $$A=PQ-QP$$

It is so natural because we know that $tr(XY-YX)=0$ for all $X,Y$.

I know some proof by induction and canonical forms. Can somebody say another easy and elementary way.

Comment: I don't think there is an easy proof. See http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/MathH110/trace0.pdf and http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.mmj/1028990168 .